# Alamofire installation problem on testing iPhone

Tags: swift, iphone, xcode, installation, alamofire

Hello I installed Alamofire 5.0 via pod and I try to run it on the real phone.

The project is empty only Alamofire and a contentView say hello world.

if a run it on  simulator it work perfect, if I run on the real phone I get the following warning. (I authorized in general setting the app)

[image: error]

any solution? I don't know what is this

```
/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/C526B7F7-4337-4D36-A9EB-C56913D97329/FlyWeatherX.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire: code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/C526B7F7-4337-4D36-A9EB-C56913D97329/FlyWeatherX.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire'
```

thanks for the help

Comment: can you please show the podfile?

Answer (score 1):

Check the version of your ios on your phone is it matching the version of ios on xCode or not.

also if your iphone under ios 13 then 
first - choose from xcode your exact iphone version from the building tap
second - delete the SceneDelegate file and then go to AppDelegate and remove the last two functions then before the first function just implement the view by writing :-> **var window: UIWindow?**

then run the project and see what is the next ..